# Событие не происходит event

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

Добрый день, есть вопрос. Есть ссылка при нажатие на нее должен зафиксировать событие. Внутри ссылки с помощью классов я вызываю эту функцию. Для проверки я написал внутри функции console.log(), но не реагирует. Вот код:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.btn-searchview', function() {
  console.log("ssssssss");
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'virtual page view'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript: void(0)" data-bind="attr: {onclick: 'SearchViewModelInstance.GoToNextPage()'}" aria-label="Next" class="btn-searchview">
                        Next »
                    </a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.btn-searchview', function() {
  console.log("ssssssss");
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'virtual page view'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn-searchview">button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.btn-searchview').click(function () {
    console.log("ssssssss");
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" class="btn-searchview">кликни на меня</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я так тоже пробовал не работает

Comment: @ИсмоилМухаммадиев, все работает, не знаю, что у вас там может не работать. Нажмите выполнить код и кликните по ссылке, все работает, в вашем же примере - не работает потому, что вы, не правильно работаете с методом `click`

Comment: ок, понятно спасибо еще раз.

Comment: @ИсмоилМухаммадиев, для спасибок - есть специальная галочка `^` возле комментария. И галочка `v` (слева от вопроса) служит для принятия решения.